# Как обойти блокировку редиректа adguard-"ом"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На сайте есть обычная форма, js проверяет ее на правильность заполнения и если все ок, то перенаправляем юзера на страницу **другого домена в новом окне**.

```
setTimeout(function(){
window.open("https://другой-домен.ру", "_blank");
}, 10);
```

Но редирект не осуществляется, а заместо этого в браузерной строке появляется сообщение "всплывающее окно заблокировано на этом сайте".

Comment: При чём тут adGuard? Это стандартная встроенная блокировка попапов. Открывайте окно сразу, а не в setTimeout

Comment: @AlexeyTen Adguard тут при том, что если отключить его, то редирект осуществляется

Comment: @MichaelMiller сделай без таймаута и все будет работать

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Вы были правы. Напишите ответом, я чекну его как "решение вопроса".

Comment: @MichaelMiller готово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай без `setTimeout` и все будет работать